# Change columns in R data frame from factor to numeric and add extra column with row sum

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big survey and I would like to calculate row totals for scales and subscales. The problem is that the columns are factors. I have created a toy example with columns converted to factors in which I try to re-convert them to numeric; I then calculate the row sum but I cannot add the sum column to the data frame. When I use the same code on my *real* data, the data structure appears to be a bit different, in a way I cannot replicate in the toy example.

This is the toy example:

```r
IUS_12_1_toy <- c(2,4,4)
IUS_12_2_toy <- c(4,5,4)
IUS_12_3_toy <- c(3,4,4)
IUS_12_4_toy <- c(4,5,3)
IUS_12_5_toy <- c(4,4,4)
IUS_12_6_toy <- c(2,5,3)
IUS_12_7_toy <- c(4,5,4)
IUS_12_8_toy <- c(4,4,4)
IUS_12_9_toy <- c(3,4,4)
IUS_12_10_toy <- c(2,3,4)
IUS_12_11_toy <- c(3,4,2)
IUS_12_12_toy <- c(1,4,2)

# convert to factor to mimic my real dataset

IUS_12_1_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_1_toy)
IUS_12_2_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_2_toy)
IUS_12_3_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_3_toy)
IUS_12_4_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_4_toy)
IUS_12_5_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_5_toy)
IUS_12_6_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_6_toy)
IUS_12_7_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_7_toy)
IUS_12_8_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_8_toy)
IUS_12_9_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_9_toy)
IUS_12_10_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_10_toy)
IUS_12_11_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_11_toy)
IUS_12_12_toy_factor <- as.factor(IUS_12_12_toy)

# create the data frame

IUS_12_toy_factor <- data.frame(IUS_12_1_toy_factor, IUS_12_2_toy_factor, IUS_12_3_toy_factor, 
                         IUS_12_4_toy_factor, IUS_12_5_toy_factor, IUS_12_6_toy_factor,
                         IUS_12_7_toy_factor,IUS_12_8_toy_factor,IUS_12_9_toy_factor,IUS_12_10_toy_factor,
                         IUS_12_11_toy_factor,IUS_12_12_toy_factor)

class(IUS_12_toy_factor)
#> [1] "data.frame"
class(IUS_12_1_toy_factor)
#> [1] "factor"

# Convert to numeric

IUS_12_toy_factor = apply(IUS_12_toy_factor, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
class(IUS_12_toy_factor)
#> [1] "matrix"
class(IUS_12_1_toy_factor)
#> [1] "factor" # why is this still a factor?

# anyway the row sum works...
rowSums(IUS_12_toy_factor)
#> [1] 36 51 42

#... but now I cannot add the column
IUS_12_toy_factor[,13] <- rowSums(IUS_12_toy_factor)
#> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , 13, value = c(36, 51, 42)): subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Then when I go to my real dataset, the situation is a bit different: the data structure is not exactly the same; the columns become atomic vectors?

```r
library(reprex)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
library(magrittr)
setwd("~/Dropbox/_Research/_CogSci/Data")
# Read CSV into R
MyData <- read.csv(file="20190904_Beads_task_Prolific_pilot_DATA_ANALYSIS.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
MyData <- MyData[-c(3), ]


# Rename columns in R (by the way, how to do this in a loop?)

names(MyData)[162]<-"IUS_12_1"
names(MyData)[163]<-"IUS_12_2"
names(MyData)[164]<-"IUS_12_3"
names(MyData)[165]<-"IUS_12_4"
names(MyData)[167]<-"IUS_12_5"
names(MyData)[168]<-"IUS_12_6"
names(MyData)[169]<-"IUS_12_7"
names(MyData)[170]<-"IUS_12_8"
names(MyData)[171]<-"IUS_12_9"
names(MyData)[172]<-"IUS_12_10"
names(MyData)[174]<-"IUS_12_11"
names(MyData)[175]<-"IUS_12_12"

class(MyData)
#> [1] "data.frame"
class(MyData$IUS_12_1)
#> [1] "factor"

#Create a dataframe with just one survey of interest

IUS_12 <- MyData[c(162,163,164, 165, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 174, 175)]
class(IUS_12)
#> [1] "data.frame"
IUS_12 <- IUS_12[-c(1,2), ]

class(IUS_12)
#> [1] "data.frame"
class(IUS_12$IUS_12_1)
#> [1] "factor"


IUS_12 = apply(IUS_12, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)));

class(IUS_12)
#> [1] "matrix"
class(IUS_12$IUS_12_1)
#> Error in IUS_12$IUS_12_1: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

# Check data structure

dput(head(IUS_12))
#> structure(c(2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
#> 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 
#> 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 
#> 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1), .Dim = c(6L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
#>     NULL, c("IUS_12_1", "IUS_12_2", "IUS_12_3", "IUS_12_4", "IUS_12_5", 
#>     "IUS_12_6", "IUS_12_7", "IUS_12_8", "IUS_12_9", "IUS_12_10", 
#>     "IUS_12_11", "IUS_12_12")))

#calculate sum of rows
rowSums(IUS_12)
#>  [1] 36 51 42 37 41 28 41 44 46 38 44 41 44 25 34 30 25 52 45 38 30 42 34
#> [24] 42 32 38

# add column
IUS_12[,13] <- rowSums(IUS_12)
#> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , 13, value = c(36, 51, 42, 37, 41, 28, 41, 44, : subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Consider reshaping your wide data to long format data which is usually the preferred structure for calculation, aggregation, plotting, and modeling. You also avoid complex, looped processes on data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `apply()` coerces your `data.frame` into a `matrix`.

You may avoid this by using `lapply()` for conversion.

```
IUS_12_toy_factor[] <- lapply(IUS_12_toy_factor, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

If you want to give the row sums column a name, you may do

```
US_12_toy_factor[,"ROWSUMS"] <- rowSums(IUS_12_toy_factor)
```

or in `$` notation:

```
IUS_12_toy_factor$ROWSUMS <- rowSums(IUS_12_toy_factor)
```

To rename columns simultaneously use `paste()`.

```
names(IUS_12_toy_factor)[-13] <- paste("IUS_12", 1:12, sep="_")
names(IUS_12_toy_factor)
# [1] "IUS_12_1"  "IUS_12_2"  "IUS_12_3"  "IUS_12_4"  "IUS_12_5"  "IUS_12_6"  "IUS_12_7" 
# [8] "IUS_12_8"  "IUS_12_9"  "IUS_12_10" "IUS_12_11" "IUS_12_12" "ROWSUMS"
```

#### Data

```
IUS_12_toy_factor <- structure(list(IUS_12_1_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
"4"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_2_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "5"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_3_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_4_toy_factor = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_5_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "4", class = "factor"), IUS_12_6_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "3", "5"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_7_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "5"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_8_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "4", class = "factor"), IUS_12_9_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_10_toy_factor = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2", 
"3", "4"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_11_toy_factor = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), IUS_12_12_toy_factor = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried `IUS_12_toy_factor[] <- lapply(IUS_12_toy_factor, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` but when I try to get the sum I get `Error in rowSums(IUS_12_toy_factor) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Comment: @Nottolina Depends on which version of `IUS_12_toy_factor` we're talking about. The code is working fine for me. I'm referring to that version I've just added to my answer (that one just before you're checkiing `class()` the very first time).

Comment: I made it work on the toy example, thank you! But it does not work on the real dataset, even though after the transformation the dataset it's a list of numeric vectors. `> dput(head(IUS_12))
list(IUS_12_1 = c(2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4), IUS_12_2 = c(4, 5,...`